# Custom Webservice for Media Upload in Umbraco 5

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

I'd like to enable BATCH MEDIA upload to UMBRACO 5.

Unfortunately all existing packages are broken, so I've started creating my own

(following this guy's nice blog here.. http://heltblank.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/multiple-file-upload-for-umbraco-5-jupiter-using-uploadify/)

My PREFERED option would be using a WCF webservice, but a BackOfficeController is also an acceptable option...

Now the QUESTIONS:

*) How do I FETCH existing media folders (for parentId) in the webservice or BackOfficeController?
*) How do I Create a new Media Item in the webservice or BackOfficeController (directly via Hive, ..) not just calling the controller as in the blog above?

I've been really in love with Umbraco for 2+ years.. but the API model for Umbraco 5 seems a bit over-engineered in my opinion.. (Hive / Get Writer / Repository / Schema /...) all similar terms that harden development work like this..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may already be aware of this but as of (13th June 2012) Umbraco 5 is officially an abandoned project due to the fact it was fundamentally flawed at the architecural level and deemed unfixable.

It was announced at the Developer Conference... you can see the reasons why in the blog post below. Suffice to say, you're advised to not use it.

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx

or watch the rather cringeworthy keynote video here :

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/cg12-keynote-video.aspx

So I recommend that you move to 4.X for the above and do above.

Thanks,